# jQuery lazyload not working on window scroll but on window resize

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I am using jquery lazyload on one of my pages.

Following is the issue scenario:

1) All images present in working viewport on window load, perfectly loads the images.

2) Once user scrolls the new images with class lazy gets into viewport but does not load as per its default behavior.

3) If you run lazyload command with say images A,B,C in viewport and D,E,F not in viewport:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

A,B,C loads but D,E,F does not load.

4) Now bring D,E,F in viewport, no image loaded. But if you resize your browser window it loads the current images in viewport.

**So lazyload module is working but its unable to detect unloaded images in viewport on scroll which is desired behavior. I think this has something to do with the dom structure of my page.**

Can somebody suggest something based on above use case, as some of you might have faced the similar issue.

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: just switch to lazysizes. it is bulletproof: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/

Answer (score 1):

This can have multiple issues. I would suggest that you use [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes), which uses modern technologies to make lazyloading config free (of course you can configure plenty of things), but it works bulletproof out of the box.

Simply a) include the lazysizes script, b) switch `src` to `data-src` and c) add the class `lazyload` to your image elements.

No additional JS is required.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Until I resize window(or open console!?) picture don't show.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({
        failure_limit : 1000, 
        event: "lazyload", 
        threshold : 200, 
        effect: "fadeIn", 
        skip_invisible: false
    })
});</script>
```